# Image View increases Table View Cell Height ultimately

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ImageView and Label inside image table view cell. Both are `equal-width` to each other.

**Constrains for Image View:**

(1) Top, Left, Bottom equal to parent.
(2) Right equal to label with constant as 8.
(3) Width equal to label

**Constrains for label:** `(number of lines = 0)`

(1) Top, Right, Bottom equal to parent.

Here [I attached the Xcode project](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/87e2eac7b9fcbfa5f04fcbe8e66652e220210531014108/ae0d44) for full understanding.

**Code:**

```
import SDWebImage

class Cell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewLeft: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        
        cell.imageViewLeft.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1931152/pexels-photo-1931152.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"), completed: nil)
        cell.label.text = """
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
            """
        return cell
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Current result is weird. **I can get the expected result at first time only**. Once I **started scroll** then then cell height is increased ultimately to fit height of the image view from the loaded image size. Please refer below screenshots.

Current result after first scroll:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

**Update:-**

I have an idea to calculate the `width` & `height` of the `Text` by following `UILabel.frame.size` & set constant height to the `Label` will solve the issue.

But I don't know how to do that calculation.

Please help to find any solution to fix this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put in a stackView image and label for tableView automatic dimension, here how to do it programmatically, below your cell an controller:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

var imageViewLeft: UIImageView = {
    
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.backgroundColor = .red
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return iv
}()

let label = UILabel()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    label.textColor = .white
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageViewLeft, label])
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    imageViewLeft.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

Your Controller looks like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let tableView = UITableView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.backgroundColor = .black
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.fillSuperview()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    
//        cell.imageViewLeft.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1931152/pexels-photo-1931152.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"), completed: nil)
    let image = UIImage(named: "profilo") // put here your urlimage, I don't have SDWebImage
    cell.imageViewLeft.image = image
    cell.label.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.label.text = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old."
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
 }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

if you want some padding from cells, set stacView constraints like this:

```
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a constraint for image with `Equal Height`

Comment: Thank you! I tried but not works. Same result.